# Who triggers CancellationTokenSource's Cancel method in .NET Core hosted service?

Tags: .net, .net-core, cancellationtokensource

I implemented the StartAsync in my class that implements IHostedService as follows:

```
public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    Token = cancellationToken;
    IsRunning = true;
    Logger.LogInformation("Service start");
    await UploadDailyTotals().ConfigureAwait(false);
    Timer.Start();
}
```

I assigned the token I received to a class variable. I'm using a timer based approach to continously run a method.

```
    async void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (IsRunning)
                await UploadDailyTotals().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.LogError(ex.GetBaseException().Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            Timer.Start();
        }
    }
```

A part of the UploadDailyTotals uses the cancellation token to stop working if cancellation is requested, but only after finishing all work in a unit like this:

```
    async Task UploadDailyTotals()
    {
        ...            
        while (sendDate <= endDate)
        {
            if (Token.IsCancellationRequested)
                return;
            ...work logic here...
        }
```

This is only a part of the method, but it contains all that I'm wondering about.
My question is does the framework trigger the CancellationTokenSource's Cancel method when shutting down the app? Before or after triggering the StopAsync method? Can I even use the token as shown here?

Comment: *...I assigned the token I received to a class variable...*. Who/what created the token? Where does it come from?

Comment: The class implements IHostedService, so it is part of the contract. As to where it comes from, I'm guessing the famework. This is how you setup that class:
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
.ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {   
                    services.AddHostedService<YourServiceClass>();
                })